# Perl's correspondent string literal for Python's prefix r"text"?

Tags: python, string, perl, literals

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/54964) is about Python's string literal `r`, while this is about Perl's one [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=String%20Literals%20in%20Perl).
However, I am not sure if there exists any equivalent command in Perl for Python's prefix `r`.

How can you replace equivalently Python's prefix r in Perl's string literals?

Comment: Well if you want a _command_, you can use `q` and `qq` to construct string literals in Perl. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators

Comment: `\ ` is special in both `q` and `qq`, though, so there's no direct correspondence to Python's `r`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The uninterpolated quote operator `q{}` will get you most of the way there. There are only a couple of subtle differences.

1. delimiters

   There are four delimiters used with Python raw string literals:

   - `r"..."` and `r'...'`
   - `r"""..."""` and `r'''...'''`

   The `q...` operator in Perl has a greater variety of delimiters

   - Paired delimiters  `q(...)`, `q[...]`, `q<...>`, `q{...}`
   - Regular delimiters can be any other non-alphanumeric, 7-bit ASCII char: `q"..."`, `q/.../`, `q#...#`, etc.
2. the backslash

   The backslash character `\` is always interpreted as a literal backslash character in Python raw literal strings. It will *also* escape a character that would otherwise be interpreted as the closing delimiter of the string

   ```
   r'Can\'t believe it\'s not butter'   =>   Can\'t believe it\'s not butter
   ```

   The backslash character `\` in a Perl `q{...}` expression is also a literal backslash with two exceptions:

   - The backslash precedes a delimiter character

     ```
     q<18 \> 17 \< 19>     =>   18 > 17 < 19
     q#We're \#1#          =>   We're #1
     ```
   - The backslash precedes another backslash character. In this case the sequence of two backslash characters is interpreted as a single backslash.

     ```
     q[single \ backslash]           =>  single \ backslash
     q[also a single \\ backslash]   =>  single \ backslash
     q[double \\\ backslash]         =>  double \\ backslash
     q[double \\\\ backslash]        =>  double \\ backslash
     ```

There is one way to create a truly "raw" string in Perl: A single-quoted here-doc.

```
my $string = <<'EOS';
'"\\foo
EOS
```

This creates the string `'"\\fooNEWLINE`.

(So is it possible to create a single raw string literal in Python that contains both `'''` and `"""`?)

Comment: Added the truest raw Perl has.

Comment: heredoc strings always end in a newline

Comment: Yup. Because there's actually a newline there.

Comment: Is there any sense of escaping all paths? Normally, I do it in Python by `r` prefix so probably the `q(...)` is the corresponding one. I just noticed that I had backflashes in some PATHS which must be escaped in prompt but not in Perl. Etc `my $file = q(/Users/masi/7-8:2015/). $fileID. q(.raw);` should work. 
While `my $file = q(/Users/masi/7-8\:2015/). $fileID. q(.raw);` is not working because of the backflash. Priting `$file` gives also the backflash which is just escaping there a thing.